# Add element to passed jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to pass a table to a function and then get the rows using jQuery. What am I doing wrong here?

```
sortTable($('#myTable'));


function sortTable(targetTable)
{
    var rows = $(targetTable + ' tr');
}
```

Error: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object].tr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
sortTable($('#myTable'));
```

You're passing `targetTable` a `jQuery object`, so adding it to a string forces it to turn into a string, which is `[object Object]`. I think you mean:

```
sortTable('#myTable');

function sortTable(targetTableSelector) {
   var rows = $(targetTableSelector+ ' tr');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.find()`:

```
var rows = targetTable.find("tr");
```

That will find all the `<tr>` elements starting from the table and give you a new jQuery object containing them.

You can get the selector that was used to construct a jQuery object:

```
var tableSelector = targetTable.selector;
```

In this case that'd be the string `"#myTable"`.  However, jQuery objects are not always formed from selectors. If you obtain a reference to the table DOM node via something like an event handler, there won't be a selector. You can still use `.find()` to locate elements from a "starting point" jQuery object.

Note that `.find()` does its work for *all* the elements in the starting jQuery collection. If your initial object was a collection including two `<table>` elements, then `.find("tr")` would find all the rows under both tables.

Answer (score 0):

Your passing in a jQuery object. Not the `id`. This means that when you concatenate your `id` to your `targetTable` argument you'll get:

```
[object Object] tr
```

Thus you'll be trying to select:

```
$("[object Object] tr")
```

Which isn't what you want. Instead, you need to pass in the table `id` into your function so that you concatenate it with a string, rather than an object.

See working example below:

```js
function sortTable(targetTable) {
    var rows = $(targetTable + ' tr').toArray();
    return rows.toArray();
}

console.log(sortTable('#myTable'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" border=1>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bob</td>
    <td>23</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>33</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Method one, passing jQuery object:

```
sortTable($('#myTable'));

function sortTable(table) {
    var rows = table.find('> tbody > tr');
}
```

Method two, passing selector string:

```
sortTable('#myTable');

function sortTable(tableSelector) {
    var rows = $(tableSelector).find('> tbody > tr');
}
```

Edit: (assuming you want only the rows within the tbody and not the head, otherwise remove "> tbody > tr")